# SVN for Emacs: how do you set author name and save password?

Tags: svn, configuration, emacs

I can't seem to find this on google anywhere. I am trying to move to emacs from eclipse but I can't for the life of me figure out how to set my svn author name so it doesn't default the author name OR save the password so I don't have to type it in any each time. I am Ubuntu 8.10 if that matters.

Any insight would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which interface do you use? I prefer [psvn](http://www.xsteve.at/prg/emacs/psvn.el), which says the following:

> Q3: How do I enter a username and password?
>
> A3: In the *svn-status* buffer press "s", switch to the
>       *svn-process* buffer and press enter. You will be prompted for
>       username and password.

As far as I know, psvn does not provide a way to save your password. Anyway, it would not be smart to store your password e.g. in your dotemacs. It's a good idea to use SVN over SSH since the command-line Subversion client (the one that psvn uses, too) can remember HTTPS passwords. In that case, you may want to generate an SSH key pair that keeps you typing your password every time. There is an [entry about it in the Subversion FAQ](http://subversion.tigris.org/faq.html#ssh-auth-cache) how you can do that.

Comment: That lets me enter my password...but doesn't allow me to save it or set my author name which is different than my username

Comment: I put in my own question on this too: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148886/how-can-i-set-the-svn-password-with-emacs-23-1-built-in-integration It looks like Emacs 23.1.1 in CentOS 6.2 has psvn.el for SVN integration but I cannot find a svn-status buffer!

Comment: OK... it seems that psvn.el was not loaded by default. Now it is and I have an *svn-status* buffer. But when I switch to the *svn-process* buffer and hit enter I get a prompt to "Send line to svn process:" and not a username and password prompt!