# Emacs: Stop popup window for gpg passphrase

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacs is annoyingly popping up window and asking for pass phrase whenever I open a encrypted file (somefile.gpg, .authinfo.gpg). I would like it instead ask me for password in minibuffer.

is there any configuration option for that.?

Edit:
Important to note, if I press escape on popup window, emacs will ask for password in minibuffer. So there is fallback exist in emacs, I like to make that fallback method as first choice.

UPDATE:
  Emacs version: GNU Emacs 24.3.50.12 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.4.2)
 of 2013-05-28 on sealion

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emacs / CVS / OpenSSH: preventing password popup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245680/emacs-cvs-openssh-preventing-password-popup)

Comment: @Thomas, Unfortunately not, I tried the solution there, no use (as I expected).

Comment: Does it happen when you run `emacs -Q`?

Comment: What's your Platform/OS/version of Emacs?

Comment: @phils Updated in question.

Comment: Have a browse through `M-x customize-group RET epg RET`. The debug options may help. Check that `epg-gpg-program` and its config files do not enforce a GUI dialog (especially when outside of Emacs). That kind of thing.

Comment: @Barmar, why this is off topic, The answer clearly involved code in it. I remember that any emacs related is not off topic to SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Now I placed the following in `.emacs` which is finally disabling the gui prompt.

```lisp
;; Do not use gpg agent when runing in terminal
(defadvice epg--start (around advice-epg-disable-agent activate)
  (let ((agent (getenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO")))
    (setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO" nil)
    ad-do-it
    (setenv "GPG_AGENT_INFO" agent)))
```

Answer (score 2):

The comments on `gpg-agent` in `C-h f epg-context-set-passphrase-callback RET` look relevant, and I can see there is plenty of related discussion and apparent workarounds for this on the Emacs Wiki, under the heading "How to use a non-graphical password prompt for gpg":

http://emacswiki.org/emacs/EasyPG#toc4

Comment: Thanks, I should have gone to wiki first.