# Disable OpenSSH popup window

Tags: linux, ssh

I tried to install gitea on my raspberry and since that an OpenSSH window pops up to write down the password for `git@192.168.1.125`. How to disable it?

Comment: what window? How does it look like? What is it asking?

Comment: @Jakuje It looks like this: [screenshot](http://imgur.com/t1M21QG)

Comment: 1) It does not look like OpenSSH. 2) How else do you want to provide password?

Comment: @Jakuje It reads OpenSSH on the border. I want to prevent to popup it. It pop ups even my terminal is closed and I changed the user what makes git operations

Comment: Is was not in the screenshot. So it is OpenSSH. But it does not answer the second question, how do you want to authenticate to that server.

Comment: I authenticate it in the terminal when I want to make configurations (ssh pi@192.168.1.125)

Comment: @Jakuje Same issue here. I would like to authenticate via authinfo.gpg

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3245680/emacs-cvs-openssh-preventing-password-popup https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826849/emacs-stop-popup-window-for-gpg-passphrase?noredirect=1&lq=1