# Reference to local directory inside org-mode 'src' block evaluated remotely via TRAMP

Tags: bash, emacs, org-mode, org-babel

Hopefully this will be an easy one to solve. I am trying to backup my personal website straight into my HDD with a compact org-mode 'src' block, which is evaluated remotely via tramp.

```
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results silent :dir /ssh:username@hostname:
  # Backup mysql database
  mysqldump -u user -p database > public_html/BACKUP.sql
  # Compress directory with the above file and the website main configs
  tar zcvf - public_html > $(date +%Y_%m)-website_backup.tar.gz
  # Remove database backup from server
  rm public_html/BACKUP.sql
#+END_SRC
```

I am happy with almost everything in the above code, however, I would like the tar command to create the output file on my machine or the HDD (locally essentially). Currently the tar.gz file is created in the remote machine. Is there a way to specify my local directory inside of the above code? Thank you in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

The final setup is as follows

```
#+NAME: remote
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results silent :dir /ssh:username@hostname:
  # Backup mysql database
  mysqldump -u user -p database > public_html/BACKUP.sql
  # Compress directory with the above file and the website main configs
  tar zcvf - public_html > $(date +%Y_%m)-website_backup.tar.gz
  # Remove database backup from server
  rm public_html/BACKUP.sql
#+END_SRC
#+NAME: local 
#+BEGIN_SRC sh :results silent :var r=remote
  echo $r
  rsync -av --remove-source-files -e ssh user@hostname:$(date +%Y_%m)-website_backup.tar.gz /path_to_HDD
#+END_SRC
```

which by executing the local block will produce the desired output. Note: It presumes the use of ssh-agent. If anyone knows how to do this with auth-source please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create another code block that's executed locally, and call `scp` or whatever from that.  Then reference the remote one in the local one.  Here's a toy example, where my machine is `shannon` and the remote one is `easybake`:

```
#+NAME: remote
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :dir /ssh:easybake:
hostname
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: remote
: easybake

#+NAME: local 
#+BEGIN_SRC shell :var r=remote
echo $r
hostname
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS: local
| easybake |
| shannon  |
```

You don't need to use the output of `remote`, the `:var` directive is what runs it.

Comment: Interesting option. I have problems with calling `scp` in a src block though. Similarly to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826849/emacs-stop-popup-window-for-gpg-passphrase#16829842) I am prompted for a password wih openssh. Ideally, auth-source should take care of everything. In this regard TRAMP works fine. I know this is a bit off-topic, but is there a way to redirect the password query to auth-source? Thanks

Comment: I don't know, I've never played with auth-source.  I always set up a key with hosts I regularly log into.  Additionally, I use `ssh-agent`, `keychain`, and the Emacs package `keychain-environment`.

Comment: I am probably better off with a setup similar to yours. It is great that it only requires execution of one source block, although it is a bit less compact. Also, I decided to use `rsync` instead of `scp` to clean the source files (as suggested by the other post). I will update my question to show the final setup. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I guess not, you'll have to use a **rsync** instruction to copy the created backup from the remote machine to yours.

See https://download.samba.org/pub/rsync/rsync.html